# How do I hide a child frame from within the frame?

Tags: jquery, parent-child

Sorry, I think I'm being rather silly and overlooking something basic, but I'm just starting out with jQuery.

Trying to write a link to hide a frame, but need to refer to the parent page from the child in order to hide it. So here's my code:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('a#closelink')click(function(){  
$(window.parent.document.getElementById('#childframe')hide('slow'));  
})  
});  
</script>
```

with the following html:
    `<a id="closelink" href="#">Close</a>`

I've also tried the following, to no avail:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a#closelink')click(function(){
$('#childframe', window.parent.document).hide('slow');
})
});
```

Comment: Are both frames on the same domain?

Comment: in your first example, you're missing a period before `hide(` and `click(`

Comment: There should be a `.` before `click(…)` and `hide(…)`.

Comment: Oh dear... /facepalm Sorry everybody, let me try that.

Comment: We've got a winner! Such a simple oversight... Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a#closelink').click(
```

and

```
('#childframe').hide(
```